# Does Objective-C nullability support affect iOS target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have been trying to determine if the new nullability support for Objective-C would have any affect on the ability to target iOS7+ (since it was introduced only last year), or is it simply a compiler thing and therefore only limits the version of Xcode you can use?

The article announcing the feature does not specify
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Parse for example decided to wrap up all the Objective-C nullability annotations in their own macros in case the _has_feature (nullable) etc is not not available. Now this very well could be just so they can stick PF_ all over the place, but I wasn't sure.

Does anyone know if native nullability support changes anything to do with the version of iOS you can target?

Comment: You know that nullability support is a feature in Objective-C that is needed for Swift?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly why I want to support it.

Comment: Okay! I asked, because you didn't mention it.

Comment: I think, too, that it depends on the compiler version only.